# do we really need to have our HTML markup to be valid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, validation

using the website at validator.w3.org you can check every website on the internet to see if it has valid HTML and CSS markup. But most sites don't and it doesn't effect anything.

So is there any need to have valid HTML markup on all our pages, or is it just so we can put the fancy `valid` badge on our page?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the benefits of being standard-compliant, not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Different browsers handle errors differently. So if you care for browser-interoperability, make sure your website validates.

Answer (score 3):

There is a *standard*. That standard is there so anyone can *write* HTML and anyone can *parse* it. If everybody would do whatever they wanted, it would be impossible to get *writers* and *parsers* to work together. Hence both sides target the standard to be able to communicate with each other. You as a writer need to adhere to the standard *as closely as possible* if you are hoping that an HTML compliant parser ever parses your HTML.

If you deviate from the standard, there's no telling what, if anything, will break. Most parsers are very lenient. That doesn't mean you can simply ignore the standard. If you deviate from it, it's up to you to test whether this breaks anything in popular parsers.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers correct for many errors. Browsers don't correct for all errors. The set of errors that a given browser will recover from will be different from the set that the next browser will recover from.

Validation finds a lot of errors. It does so quickly and easily.

Finding an error that is causing you a problem with a validator is a lot easier if you don't have to look at 499 other errors and think "No, the browser can recover from *that* one".

So no, you don't have to have valid markup, but it saves a lot of time in the long run for not much effort.

Answer (score 0):

Imho, being 100% standards-compliant is good, but not a 'conditio sine qua non' (an inevitable condition for it to work). Errors found by validators (the most popular one being the W3C validator) include a lot of errors that will not break your code.

For example, omitting an `alt=""` attribute to your images is considered as error, and while doing so is bad, in my knowledge it doesn't break on any browser. 
Other cases include external scripts/links implemented into the page that may generate errors. Some validators may perhaps throw errors at custom data-attributes, etc.

The official Belgian (northern) bus company website http://www.delijn.be gets 67 errors and 32 warnings from the W3C validator. Still it is the official website and people buy their tickets online and look up the information they need without problems.

**My conclusion: Even though you should try to make your pages as standards-compliant as possible, you as a human have a sense of judgment (and browser experience hopefully) about what will and will not be a crucial error. A standard is a standard, it is a guide that you are free and encouraged, but not forced to follow.**